# Java Threads Not Running Asynchronously - Some not completing at all

Tags: java, multithreading

I am attempting to complete an experiment for a university project.  I want to run it in parallel, utilising multiple cores, so that I can increase the sample size.  To achieve this I am creating multiple (up to 7, but I have tried using as few as 2) java threads and executing my class in all of those threads at once.  My PC has 8 cores.

The problem I am having is that Java seems to be haphazard in how those threads are executed.  All 7 threads start fine.  They run asynchronously for a while.  In a typical run maybe 3 of them will finish in the expected time, a fourth might finish a few minutes later and the final 3 don't finish at all.

The experimental class is designed to run for a certain amount of wall-clock time (not cpu-clock time).  This factor is outside of my control.  So I need my threads to be running simultaneously on separate cores at all times.

The following code snippet exhibits the method I am using to create the threads and kick them off.  It is obviously not calling the class I am using for my experiment and if you copy it and run it yourself, you will see that it works fine.  I have provided it here simply to demonstrate that I am creating and using the threads correctly.  I have been searching for an answer to this for days and can't see that I am doing anything wrong.

This is a test class demonstrating the means used by my experimental class.  It just concatenates some string data to ensure a long enough running process.

```
public class ThreadTestClass implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    System.out.println("This thread is underway");
    int i=0;
    String a="a";
    while(i<25){
        a=a+a;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("This thread ran fine");

}

}
```

This is how it is called:

```
   private static void ThreatTestMethod(){
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[7];
    int i=0;

    while(i<threads.length){
        threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadTestClass());
        threads[i].start();
        i++;
    }

    while(threads[0].isAlive() || threads[1].isAlive() || threads[2].isAlive() || threads[3].isAlive() || threads[4].isAlive() || threads[5].isAlive() || threads[6].isAlive()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception Occurred");
        }
    }

}
```

My understanding is that Java should be automatically utilising all of the cores, and that when I execute my threads they should utilise all available cores.  That is normally what happens.  It is not happening when I run my experiment.  Is there anything I can do to force the threads to run simultaneously on separate cores?

Comment: you can't force threads.

Comment: JVM doesn't guarantee that all threads will run simultaneously on all available cores.

Comment: OK. The academic literature is loaded with people claiming to use multiple cores to run their java-based experiments.  Are they using some means other than threading?  Do I have any other options to run my experiment in parallel?

Comment: you are saying some threads don't complete. That should not happen. And its not happening with me.

Comment: Hi Batty, as I said, the code snippets I provided work fine.  It's when I run my experiment that I encounter the problem.  I provided the snippets as a means to demonstrate the means I am using to kick off the threads without having to publish thousands of lines of code.

Comment: So if you expect all seven threads to be running at once, what output are you actually seeing? btw I suspect an issue here is setting priority to MAX_PRIORITY

Comment: If threads are not finishing, it is probably because something has gone south in your code. Set up logging to monitor the progress of your tasks and what they are doing. Use a `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` to catch any exceptions. Use a `ThreadPool` to save yourself some typing.

Comment: When I test the experiment, I set it to run for 1 minute.  When I do that, 2 or 3 threads finish in 1 minute, 1 or 2 then finish about 2 minutes later and the others don't finish.  Maybe they would if I allowed them to run for longer (I have given them up to 20 minutes), but the simple fact that they didn't finish in 1 minute renders the experiment invalid anyway.

Comment: @Jimbo Threads use OS scheduling/allocation. If you're using fork/join on JDK 7 it's *likely*, but not *guaranteed*, that multiple cores will be used.

Comment: The output I am seeing is text in the console window.  I add println statements to signal it has started, one that repeats with every iteration as the experiment runs and another to show it has finished.  The output shows that at some point, before the thread has finished and while it is still "Alive()" all remaining threads stop outputting any text.

Comment: @mbatchkarov Thanks for the suggestion.  If something is going wrong in my code, it only happens when I execute it in multiple threads.  I guess that's what I will look for next.  I'll add some additional logging and try to lock down exactly where the failing threads are failing.

Comment: @Jimbo printlns and "additional logging" are what you use before you discover the Debugger. Use a debugger; you won't regret it.

Comment: @Slim.  I am using the eclipse debugger for the most part.  I'm just not sure how I'd go about doing anything useful with it when investigating an issue that only exists when running multiple threads.  Surely the act of setting breakpoints and such things would influence the thread scheduling?  Kind of like the observer effect in QM.  Maybe I need Schrodinger's debugger =D

Comment: @Jimbo Don't set any breakpoints. When you think it should have finished, click on one of the threads that's still running, and pause it. Then let the debugger tell you where it's at.

Comment: @matt - Setting max priority was just something I added to try to correct the issue.  I get the problem with or without setting priority.

Comment: @slim I didn't know you could do that.  Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code is fine.

If some of your threads aren't returning, either they're blocking (e.g. on a read(), write(), wait()), or they're stuck in a loop; just like any other program that doesn't return. Attach a debugger, or just get a stack trace dump, to find out what they're doing.

The Java API gives you no means to specify how threads are allocated to cores. It's implementation dependent, depending both on the Java implementation and on the operating system.

*However* in practice, you'll find that as long as you have a reasonably up-to-date Java, threads will be spread between cores.

Comment: OK, so I've used the debugger to identify where it gets stuck and here is what I have found.

Comment: The threads that get stuck, are all stuck on the same line of code at the same time.

However, the line of code they get stuck on is different every time I run it.

It never gets stuck on any line of code at all - and I have tried this literally thousands of times - when only a single thread is used.

Comment: It is doing something when it is stuck.  It is maxing out the cpu.  Unfortunately I am unable to see precisely what it is doing because it is always on a method provided in a third-party framework I am using.

If the location it was stuck on was completely random, that is the exact behaviour I would expect, because those methods are far more time-expensive than any of my code.

Comment: Sounds like your threads are sharing some object that's not thread-safe. Check whether it's an object you manage yourself; if not you'll have to raise it with whoever supports your 3rd party libs.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.  A deadlock or something of that nature.  I might try just creating multiple copies of the project and run it in parallel from different work spaces.

Comment: For the record, I was able to achieve the necessary parallelism by simply making multiple copies of the project and then kicking it off once in each of the projects.  It's messy but good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In short - no.

There are multiple factors influencing the scheduling of different tasks and threads over the processors available. Most obvious may be the JVM, the hardware and the actual scheduler you are running. There is no simple way to force this or to guarantee to run each thread on a different core.

There may be different ways of making it more probable that they will end up on different cores, though, but I think you might have reached the end of the line with threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your string concat is trivial - almost a no-op.

Your threads are probably spending most of their time blocked on the System.Out I/O lock, so not running at all.

If you are going to start threads, give them some reasonable work to do.

Comment: Are you serious?  It's doubling the amount of text to be concatenated 25 times.  By the time it gets to the 25th loop it's concatenating 3.3MB of data.

Comment: It ran incredibly quickly on my system, leading me to wonder whether HotSpot is doing something clever to avoid concatenating 3.3MB of data.